# How to recursively change the colour of labels in multiple forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, foreach

I have a little application with a settings form. There, a certain button when clicked will change the colour of all the labels in Panel4 in each of the forms `(Basic, Easy, Medium, Hard, Advanced)`. I have gotten this to work one-by-one with the For-Each loop as below:

```
For Each lbl As Label In Basic.Panel4.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
            lbl.ForeColor = Color.White
Next

For Each lbl As Label In Easy.Panel4.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
      etc...
```

I want to know if there is a more efficient way to carry this out rather than repeating essentially the same thing 5 times. I tried the following:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of Form) From {Basic, Easy, Medium, Hard, Advanced}
For Each frm As Form In lst
    For Each lbl As Label In frm.Panel4.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
        lbl.ForeColor = Color.White
    Next
Next
```

But get an error that `'Panel4' is not a member of 'Form'`

Comment: Why do you have a control named `Panel4`? You should ALWAYS specify a descriptive name for EVERYTHING. That you can have added four `Panels` and left each one with a meaningless name is disturbing. Your form names are bad too because reading them in isolation gives no indication that they are forms or even controls. They could be memnbers of an `Enum` and, based on the names, I would expect that they were. Bad naming is bad programming.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, will change the Panel names now. Regarding Form names, is FormBasic, etc. fine?

Comment: Personally, I recommend not prefixing with types or abbreviations of type. Name things how you speak. You click an OK button so the button should be named `okButton`. Similarly, form names should end with "Form", "Window", "Dialogue" or whatever is most appropriate for the purpose. I wouldn't use `BasicForm` though, because it's not the form that is basic. The form displays some sort of data and it is that data that is basic, so the name should reflect that, e.g. `BasicRecordForm`. You should be able to pretty much tell what a type is for simply by reading the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the generic type of your `List` is `Form` and the `Form` class has no member named `Panel4`. You have a number of specific types that each have a specific member with that name, but the common name doesn't make them the same member anyway. There are s couple of ways you could handle this.

First, the quick and dirty way. It's a small adjustment to what you're already doing:

```vb
Dim forms As Form() = {Basic, Easy, Medium, Hard, Advanced}

For Each frm In forms
    For Each lbl As Label In frm.Controls("Panel4").Controls.OfType(Of Label)
        lbl.ForeColor = Color.White
    Next
Next
```

Note that the first change is using an array to store the forms rather than a collection. The whole point of a collectyion is that it grows and shrinks as required. If you're never changing the list after you create it, what's the point of that?

The important change is in the inner loop though. The `Form` class has a `Controls` property and you can index that by name to get a specific control. All your `Panels` have the same name so you can use that technique to get access to each one. That returns a `Control` reference, but that's all you need to get its `Controls` collection to then access each `Label`.

The proper way to handle this would be to start by creating a base form with one or more specific members and then deriving each of your other five forms from that. Such a form might include code like this:

```vb
Public Class ColouredLabelForm

    Protected Property LabelPanel As Panel

    Public Sub SetLabelForeColors(colour As Color)
        For Each lbl In LabelPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
            lbl.ForeColor = colour
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Each of your derived forms might then look like this:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LabelPanel = Panel4
    End Sub

End Class
```

The code to change all the `Labels` then becomes this:

```vb
Dim forms As ColouredLabelForm() = {Basic, Easy, Medium, Hard, Advanced}

For Each frm In forms
    frm.SetLabelForeColors(Color.White)
Next
```

The right way to make changes to controls or data in forms is ALWAYS to get the form to do it itself, not to do it to the form from the outside. You tell the form what to do from the outside and then the form does it.

Comment: Regarding your first way, I am receiving the following error: `System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'OfType' on type 'ControlCollection' not found.'`

Comment: I didn't actually test that code fully and it appears that type inference on the array does not work, maybe because they are default instances. I have adjusted the code accordingly.

Comment: I don't see how you could not be able to use `OfType` when you were already doing it in your original code. It is an extension method and a member of the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class. As with all extension methods, you must have imported the namespace that its type is a member of, i.e. `System.Linq`, either at the project or file level. It is declared in the `System.Core.dll` assembly, so you must have referenced that too.